# script to fetch the list of deprecated api in the latest Java version

Tags: java

I am trying to find out a way(script or Java) by which i can fetch the list of deprecated API (classes, interfaces, methods, fields,etc) of the latest Java Version ( or any given version) into a csv file.

My output would be a csv file with something like

> /Interface/Method/Field                              | Deprecated reason/Remedy
>   org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerTaskExecutionException | The Timer's main loop will simply stop if a TimerTask throws an exception.

Comment: @Basil, Please share the link of the question which has already been answered

Comment: ?? The original Question of this duplicate is automatically displayed by the Stack Overflow system, the link appearing at the top of this page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use 3rd party libraries

Example:

- [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/csv/)
- Open CSV
- Flatpack
- CSVeed